# Add and Remove Class from multiple elements with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a tab navigation that sits above and below a block of content.
I want the active tab to be highlighted by using the class `active-tab`. By default, the first tab is the active tab. When clicking on one of the other tabs, I want that tab to be highlighted as the active tab.

My HTML structure looks like this

```
<ul class="tab-navigation">
    <li class="tab active-tab" rel="tab1">First tab</li>
    <li class="tab" rel="tab2">Second tab</li>
    <li class="tab" rel="tab3">Third tab</li>
</ul>
<div>
    <div class="tab_container">
        <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">Some Content</div>
        <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">Some Content</div>
        <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">Some Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
<ul class="tab-navigation">
    <li class="tab active-tab" rel="tab1">First tab</li>
    <li class="tab" rel="tab2">Second tab</li>
    <li class="tab" rel="tab3">Third tab</li>
</ul>
```

The jQuery code looks like this:

```
$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show();

$("ul.tab-navigation li").click(function() {
    
    $(".tab_content").hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
    $("#"+activeTab).fadeIn();      
    
    $("ul.tab-navigation li").removeClass("active-tab");
    $(this).addClass("active-tab");
    
});
```

The jQuery code above works but it only adds and removes the `active-tab` class for the tab navigation that was used. If I use the navigation above the content, it will only change the class for the tabs above the content but not for the ones below. However, I want it to update the class on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are getting `rel` value you can use this as  a selector to add active class to required divs i.e : `$(".tab-navigation li[rel="+activeTab+"]")` .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(".tab_content").hide();
$(".tab_content:first").show();

$("ul.tab-navigation li").click(function() {
  $(".tab_content").hide();
  var activeTab = $(this).attr("rel");
  $("#" + activeTab).fadeIn();
  $("ul.tab-navigation li").removeClass("active-tab");
  //add class where rel matches
  $(".tab-navigation li[rel=" + activeTab + "]").addClass("active-tab");

});
```

```css
.active-tab {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tab-navigation">
  <li class="tab active-tab" rel="tab1">First tab</li>
  <li class="tab" rel="tab2">Second tab</li>
  <li class="tab" rel="tab3">Third tab</li>
</ul>
<div>
  <div class="tab_container">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab_content">Some Content1</div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab_content">Some Content2</div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab_content">Some Content3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<ul class="tab-navigation">
  <li class="tab active-tab" rel="tab1">First tab</li>
  <li class="tab" rel="tab2">Second tab</li>
  <li class="tab" rel="tab3">Third tab</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. And also thanks for the explanation. I will mark it as the correct answer as soon as the system lets me do it.